# How do you get the latest version/master of a package in bower?

Tags: backbone.js, bower, backbone-forms

I had the problem with backbone-forms, where I needed to draw from master branch (because of a fix that was not yet tagged). I was trying all kinds of combinations.

`{
   'backbone-forms': ?
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is say:

```
{
   'package-name': 'master'
}